# Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin with containerd

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, containerd

I'm currently using a podtemplate (See below) inside my `Jenkinsfile` to provision a docker container which mounts to the docker socket to provision containers within the pipeline.

As the cloud-hosted kubernetes I use is going from dockerd to containerd as container runtime, I want to ask if there is somebody who is using containerd with jenkins kubernetes plugin (especially podtemplates).

```
podTemplate(label: 'mypod', cloud: cloud, serviceAccount: serviceAccount, kubenamespace: kubenamespace, envVars: [
envVar(key: 'NAMESPACE', value: kubenamespace),
envVar(key: 'REGNAMESPACE', value: regnamespace),
envVar(key: 'APPNAME', value: appname),
envVar(key: 'REGISTRY', value: registry)
],
volumes: [
  hostPathVolume(hostPath: '/etc/docker/certs.d', mountPath: '/etc/docker/certs.d'),
  hostPathVolume(hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock')
],
containers: [
  containerTemplate(name: 'helm', image: 'lachlanevenson/k8s-helm:v2.9.1', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
  containerTemplate(name: 'docker' , image: 'docker:17.06.1-ce', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')]) {
```

Comment: Most probably the containerd socket can be used:

I found the following Link from Kubernetes: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/ 

containerd endpoint (default "unix:///var/run/containerd.sock")
However, it did not work with docker:17.06 base image.

Comment: Btw I'm alokrajiv from JIRA :)  .. did try to contact the IBM Team ... still in pursuit. No soln yet.

Comment: Went back to 1.10 for now.

Answer (score 1):

The folder structure is slightly different between the Docker engine and containerd. Specifically the containerd runtime has the following directories...

logs - /var/log/pods/
websocket - unix:////var/run/containerd/containerd.sock

This link has more details.
https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/master/docs/ops.md

Comment: Even with this hostmount in place it wont work:

(tried to run a docker:18.06 container and execute an docker command)

Error: failed to create containerd task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker pull jenkins\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Answer (score 1):

The Containerd socket within IKS 1.11 (unix:////var/run/containerd/containerd.sock) does not support mounting it and executing docker commands, thus running docker builds in IKS or any other Kubernetes Containerd setup is not supported.

We will use [Google Container Tools](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib) for docker operations inside the cluster.